# Draw only specified pixels and not whole scene?

Tags: povray

Is it possible to ask povray to draw only a portion of a scene rather than a whole scene? So specify a set of pixels to be drawn?

Answer (score 0):

Just click and drag on the render output window. It will then ask if you want to render only that portion for the next render.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Start_Column`, `End_Column`, `Start_Row` and `End_Row` command-line options. For instance, to render only the bottom right quarter of a 320x240px image:

`povray +W320 +H240 Start_Column=160 End_Column=320 Start_Row=120 End_Row=240 scene.pov`